# Find an example of a finite odd order group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Can someone help me find a concrete, easy to grasp example of a finite odd order group.

Comment: All fields $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ prime, $p\ne 2$.

Comment: Finite cyclic groups of odd order are easy to grasp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$ ?